A few doubts regarding Hegel's Sense Certainty
I, after reading commentaries and being patient with time, understood Hegel's concept of sense-certainty as a distinction between the Subject and the Object only, this type of consciousness or knowledge tells nothing about the Object (that is about its properties), it merely distinguishes the Subject and the Object, and that too with a mere 'This'.
Then Hegel goes on to defy the notion that this is an immediate knowledge, putting forth the argument that the Object, known as 'This, is 'This', and 'Here' and 'Now' for a Subject, therefore it is through the Subject the Object "is".
Now, my doubt is: does Hegel really assume there is a sense organ? I mean the title sense-certainty is plaguing me from a long time, does it imply that consciousness has organs which interacts with the objects and in the first instance, that is with the first sensation, the consciousness only knows 'This'? I'm little disinclined to believe such a schema, as starting from Descartes and all the way through Kant and Hegel (though Spinoza's system was different, yet in his system also there was no interaction between mind and body) the primary/core idea behind their philosophy is that 'body' doesn't exist, only the Consciousness exists and if that is true the phrase 'sense-certainty' seems to carry a little to no meaning.
Another doubt is: this topic of Sense-Certainty seems very odd, it seems only a good way to start, is any other philosopher (I would prefer Kant) concerned about it? If so, please recommend me some original reading of Idealists who philosophized on this topic.

Sense-certainty is not a distinction but rather the initial attitude of consciousness towards the immediately given by senses. It does oppose bare subject to bare objects as mere "these". Consciousness does not know so, it only attends to them so. It then passes to a more refined attitude according to Hegel's general thesis that the 'immediate' (intuitions) is, in fact, mediated, namely, mediated conceptually, see SEP:"Hegel seems to want to make this point without relying on Kant’s formal distinction between concepts and intuitions."
